# How to Stream files into a Zip from Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, streaming

I'm using [*the PHP Flysystem*](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/) package to stream content from my *Amazon S3* bucket. In particular, I'm using [`$filesystem->readStream`](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/#using-streams-for-reads-and-writes).

**My Question**

When I stream a file, it ends up in *myzip.zip* and the size is correct, but when unzip it, it become *myzip.zip.cpgz*. Here is my prototype:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Description: File Download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="myZip.zip"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3'); // Laravel Syntax
echo $s3->readStream('directory/file.jpg');
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Side Question**

When I stream a file like this, does it:

1. get fully downloaded into my server's RAM, then get transferred to the client, or
2. does it get saved - in chunks - in the buffer, and then get transferred to the client?

Basically, is my server being burdened if I have have dozens of GB's of data being streamed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently dumping the raw contents of the `directory/file.jpg` as the zip (which a jpg is not a zip) . You need to create a zip file with those contents.

Instead of

```php
echo $s3->readStream('directory/file.jpg');
```

Try the following in its place using the [Zip extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php):

```php
// use a temporary file to store the Zip file
$zipFile = tmpfile();
$zipPath = stream_get_meta_data($zipFile)['uri'];
$jpgFile = tmpfile();
$jpgPath = stream_get_meta_data($jpgFile)['uri'];

// Download the file to disk
stream_copy_to_stream($s3->readStream('directory/file.jpg'), $jpgFile);

// Create the zip file with the file and its contents
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipPath);
$zip->addFile($jpgPath, 'file.jpg');
$zip->close();

// export the contents of the zip
readfile($zipPath);
```

Using `tmpfile` and `stream_copy_to_stream`, it will download it in chunks to a temporary file on disk and not into RAM

Comment: What is tmpfile() in this case? Is that supposed to be getting the path to the temporary file?

Comment: @mark.inman PHP's [tmpfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) function
"Creates a temporary file with a unique name in read-write (w+) mode and returns a file handle."
To get the path to the temporary file, you perform the [stream_get_meta_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) function and access its return value's `uri` as show with `$zipPath` and `$jpgPath`